# Finding my network's public IP address range

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, setup, amazon-web-services

I am referring to the following instructions to setup Amazon EC2 web services on my local machine: [AWS-Security-Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-a-base-security-group)

I do not know how to complete the first bullet under step 6.

1. How do I find my network's public IP address range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know how to complete the first bullet under step 6.
>
> How do I find my network's public IP address range?

Step 6 is referring to what public IP address space(s) you would like to allow to communicate to your EC2 space, specifically HTTP(80) and HTTPS(443).

If you're intending on accessing your EC2 space from your home network, you can simply type `what is my ip address` in a Google search bar from you're home computer, or navigate to https://whatsmyip.org or a comparable search result using the afermentioned key words.

If you're public IP address space is dynamically assigned by your carrier via DCHP, you may need to specify the subnet(s) you ISP is leasing in your area. If you'd prefer to use your specific address as a /32 (eg. 1.1.1.1/32), you'll need to keep track of you public IP address and modify you EC2 Inbound rules accordingly.

The link below is a Google gadget that will show you you're public IP address as well as provide other information about you computer/provider.

[What's My IP Gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=aruljohn.com/gadget/ip.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Internet from home or a small business, you will probably have a single IP address. You can check it by using a service such as [this](http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/). Enter this address and /32 at the end. This will look something like 1.2.3.4/32. The address can change between uses and you might need to change it accordingly when you want to access the machine.

If you're using a enterprise network and is assigned different public addresses when connecting to the network you will probably want to ask the network administrator. This can look like 1.2.0.0/16 or 1.2.3.0/24 depending on the size of the network.

Personally I would allow it from all hosts entering the address (0.0.0.0/0) if it's not a critical machine. But this might be undesirable from a security point of view.